# Will a regression model be linear if cross term is included?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear

I am reading a book on multiple linear regression by using MATLAB. The example shows a case when a cross term is included as

$$ Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1XT + \beta_2X^2$$

In MATLAB, we rewrite the model in matrix form such that

```
N=1024;
% Y is a column vector with size = N, reads from a file
% x is a column vector with size = N, reads from a file
% t is a column vector with size = N, reads from a file
C = [ones(N,1) x.*t x.^2]
```

and hence we could use regress to solve it as

```
regress(Y, C)
```

I am quite confusing when there is a cross term, why this model is still linear? I may be wrong but it seems them the interaction between X and T will break the linearity. I just don't know how to prove it is or not.

Comment: The intended sense of 'linear' is discussed d in numerous posts already on site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is a linear combination of the inputs. Form of the input features does not matter; for example, $y=\beta_0+\beta_1\sin e^x$ can still be a linear regression model. We can always call our features with different names, e.g. let $u_1=xt,u_2=x^2$, then your model becomes:
$$y=\beta_0+\beta_1u_1+\beta_2u_2=u^T\beta$$
which is linear.

**Edit**: An example of nonlinear regression:

$$y=e^{-bx}+c$$
where we aim to find $b$ and $c$. You won't be able to represent the problem as $y=u^T\beta$, where $\beta=[b\ c]^T$.

Comment: Thanks. I see how this redefining the variables makes it linear. But could you send me an example of a nonlinear regression model?

Comment: @user1285419 I've edited my post with an example of nonlinear regression.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be linear if we worked with the series expansion of $e^{-bx}$? Ignoring the issue of estimating infinitely many parameters, why, then, isn’t this linear?

Comment: Here, we're interested in linearity in classical sense, so the dimensions should be finite. There is also research going on infinite dimensional spaces, however you won't come across it as *linear regression*.

Comment: @Dave Which series are you thinking of? If it's Maclaurin i.e. $1-bx+{b^2\over2}x^2+\cdots$ then there's the problem of $b$ appearing more than once (and even in higher orders!) in the expansion...